# Issues with merging of CSV files - Python

Tags: list, csv, merge

I am reading a book(foundation for analytics with python) and trying to merge CSV files. I searched for this issue, but didn't find a relevant answer to resolve it.

My issue is-->

> input_path = sys.argv[1] IndexError: list index out of range

my code is -->

```
import csv
import glob
import os 
import sys

input_path = sys.argv[1]
output_file = sys.argv[2]

first_file = True
for input_file in glob.glob(os.path.join(input_path, 'csv_*')):
    print(os.path.basename(input_file))
    with open(input_file, 'r', newline='') as csv_in_file:
        with open(output_file, 'a', newline='') as csv_out_file:
            filereader = csv.reader(csv_in_file)
            filewriter = csv.writer(csv_out_file)
            if first_file:
                for row in filereader:
                    filewriter.writerow(row)
                first_file = False
            else:
                header = next(filereader)
                for row in filereader:
                    filewriter.writerow(row)
```

Please help me with it.

Comment: How are you running the program?

Comment: i am studying with codeacademy and reading the book

Answer (score 0):

I solved(exactly my colleague's help) it.
i didn't input exact path when i used cmd....
So foolish Question!! idiot questioner!!!!

```
csv_merge.py "C:\pathpathpath\csv_merge" output.csv
```